# Android JNI what is current working directory for C/C++ executed code?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

In Android if an C/C++ shared library created using NDK is invoked and it loads a file what is its currently working directory?  Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The current directory is "/", not the application directory:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

char cwd[1024];
if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "", cwd);
```

To get the application directory, you need to use JNI calls to Java code, which in turn gets android application directory from Context.

Answer (score 2):

Negative. Native code getcwd() will return '/', which is not the application directory. To let native know where it is, must pass application directory (obtained from Context object) to native deliberately via a native method.
Or try to call Context's method with native codes, which is too complex.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe NDK sample at "android-ndk-rxx/samples/two-libs" will give you some useful message.